# Execute ENTRYPOINT from base image in build stage

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using a code generator tool which is provided as a Docker image with an `ENTRYPOINT`. I.e. for the manual use case I execute the following command line:

```shell
$ docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local some/codegen-image:latest \
    generate  ... parameters for code generator tool ...
```

So far, so good.

But I want to integrate the code generator image into my own multi-stage image build. I.e. the first stage should call the `ENTRYPOINT` of the base image to generate the code that will be consumed by the second stage:

```
# stage 1
FROM some/codegen-image:latest as codegen

... build set up steps for stage 1 ...

# now run ENTRYPOINT from base image, copy & pasted from the output of
#
#  docker inspect -f '{{json .Config.Entrypoint}}' some/codegen-image:latest
#
RUN ["some_command", "option1", ..., "optionN",    \
        "generate",                                \
        ... parameters for code generator tool ... \
    ]

# stage 2
FROM some/other-image as stage2

... build set up steps for stage 2 ...

# copy-in generated code from stage 1
COPY --from=codegen /tmp/build/ .
```

This works but it violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), i.e. I need to update my `Dockerfile` every time the upstream project makes an incompatible change to its `ENTRYPOINT`.

Can I avoid the copy & paste from `docker inspect` output? My own research has turned up nothing so far...

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Stage Dockerfile was introduced to optimize the overall size of the container [docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

The FROM directive just brings the content of the image specified, but you have to explicitly tell the container what command should be executed.

The feature you are expecting is not yet supported by docker.
Eg.

```
FROM some/codegen-image:latest as codegen
ARGS_ENTRYPOINT_OF_CODEGEN ["generate","parameters"]
.
.
.
FROM some/other-image as stage2
COPY --from=codegen /tmp/build/ .
```

It seems your approach is correct at this moment and the only way around.